# Second HDD's read/write speed dropped suddenly

Tags: hard-drive, sata, speed

OS is installed on SSD and the second HDD is just a storage for games. I have it for 4-5 years already and never had a problem with it. 
Sometimes I do benchmarks to monitoring my system's health but few days ago when I did another bench it said that my HDD's read/write speed dropped down much.

This is what I had before 
http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/5707192

And this what I had for last few days 
http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/5776513

It became 2-3 times slower than it was suddenly!

I have all drivers up-to-date as long as all windows 10 updates. I did not do any soft/hardware changes that can caused it. 
What i tried to do already:

- Checked SMART status in HDTune/AIDA64 - it is OK
- Did defragmentation
- Tried to change mb ports and SATA cabel
- The most important - tested an HDD on my sister's computer, nothing changed.

Because of it I think it is faulty hard drive, not OS/drivers/something else. Am I right? Or what can caused such changes? I really think to just buy a new one.

Comment: Yes, hardware failure is a logical assumption when a five-year-old piece of equipment suddenly start having problems.

Comment: Yep, I think so too. It is just strange that the SMART status and etc is ok and everything functions normally except this speed problem.

Comment: You should use SeaTools and perform a long test on the drive. First backup any data you need!

Comment: Did it already and HDD passed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted and it returned my HDD's speed back.

Comment: **No**, if the problem was resolved, information describing the resolution is an answer, and it *does* belong in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is clean up the drive with help of Acronis True Image or/and System Clean-up

https://www.acronis.com/en-us/blog/posts/power-user-insights-create-spotless-system-system-clean